# Volley getting an error response

Tags: android, http-post, android-volley

I am sending some post data using volley. Here is my code . It's a snippet from background service. Let me know if you want other files also. I've added the internet permission.

```
    public void onLocationChanged(final Location location) {
        mCurrentLocation = location;
        pref.setLocation(location);

        String url = getResources().getString(R.string.hostname); // it's a normal http 

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Location sent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                        String errorMessage = "Err - data:"+error.getMessage();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
              })
                    {
                        @Override
                        protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
                            Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                            params.put(KEY_USERID,pref.getUserId());
                            params.put(KEY_LAT,String.valueOf(location.getLatitude()));
                            params.put(KEY_LNG,String.valueOf(location.getLongitude()));
                            return params;
                        }

                    };
        queue.add(stringRequest);
    }
```

Comment: Which error you get? share your error details....

Comment: not able to get error, device is not connected to android studio.(it's a client device),  Any idea to get a log from that device without installing android studio ?

Comment: yes you can use 'crease report' or 'instabug' in your code. it's very helpful to you without installing android studio that report send directly to your mail id.

Comment: @RikzPatel i tried to use acra, but my app is not crashing, it simply not able to connect to network, What else i can do ?

Comment: Have you verified that it's not your client's device that is causing the problems?

Comment: yes i've verified it, post request is working from his mobile browser, and same error is coming from other devices

Comment: so i suggest one thing you used 'Ok Http' rather than volley...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually i saw that the one of the param UserId was having the Null value, That was creating the problem